# Can a Jamaican who was deported from the US travel to other CARICOM member nations?

Tags: international-travel

I would like to visit other Caribbean islands from Jamaica, but because I was deported from the US, I would like to know if there are any laws barring me from traveling to other CARICOM member nations.

Comment: What were you deported for? Lying? Overstaying? Violating visa terms? Crime?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific, please? As a Jamaican, you are allowed visa-free entry to nearly all of the member states (but may require a visa for some, such as British Overseas Territories, Dutch constituent countries, US Territory/Puerto Rico). With 28 members, associates, observers, your question is a bit too broad.